# PHP + jQuery, drag and drop files

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to know if there are any good scripts for managing your ftp files. Preferably with drag and drop functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there aren't any drag and drop managers (it would take a lot of messing around to do, but it's possible with AJAX or something), but there *is* [Net2FTP](http://www.net2ftp.com/). The site has a usable demo, but you can download it and put it on your own server.

I like your idea of web based drag and drop FTP... Maybe a future project for myself? ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah... Welcome to StackOverflow! Enjoy your stay :-)

Comment: Thank you :) So far this is the best one ive found: http://www.ajaxplorer.info/wordpress/

Comment: That looks pretty good! Net2FTP looks a bit crap after seeing that... :-P